# OpenSessionInViewFilter +Redirect in JSF

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf, jsf-2

I have JSF 2.1 application uisng Spring and Hibernate.

In order to solve LazyLoading problem I'm using OpenSessionInView Filter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Everything works fine my lazy classes are initiated, but when I'm using Navigation Rule with Redirect

```
 <navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
       <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
       <redirect />
   </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I'm getting `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:` id I remove `<redirect />` tag everything works fine.

Why? Is it because new View has been created? So why do I have new Hibernate Session?
Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<redirect />` is implemented by returning 301 (or 303) response code to the browser, thereby **completing** current request and closing your current (Hibernate) session.

Browser then submits a **new** request to the URL provided, resulting in brand new (Hibernate) session which your not-yet-initialized entities are not bound to.

You will either need to manually trigger initialization in existing request prior to redirect (if possible) or re-fetch all the necessary entities again after the redirect.