# OpenSessionInViewFilter doesnt work in a JSF+Spring+Hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf-2

I want to use OpenSessionInViewFilter in my JSF 2.1+Spring 3.1+Hibernate 3.6.6 project
in order to get rid of the .LazyInitializationException.
Although i declare the filter in web.xml i keep getting ;

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: pts.entity.Invention.inventors, no
>   session or session was closed

**My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.tt</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>excite-bike</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**My applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-security.xml" />   

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pts.component" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>pts.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/PTS" /> 
        <property name="username" value="root" /> <property name="password" 
            value="" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
        name="template">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="pts.scope.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I use spring managed(HibernateTemplate) hibernate daos for db operations.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to be sure that you are not redirecting between JSF view for example:

In this view your Open Session in vew Filter will work:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>start.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page1.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

and if you modify this example this way:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>start.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Your Filter will bnot help you because you are redirecting and this is completely new request and your original Hibernate session is already closed.

Inspired by this post:
[OpenSessionInViewFilter +Redirect in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819539/opensessioninviewfilter-redirect-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

When does it fail? I can see that you use Spring Security and have springSecurityFilterChain defined in you web.xml. And would assume that filter loads user from database and user has lazy collection that is accessed later, when Hibernate session created during authentication is propably closed, before OpenSessionInView filter starts executing.

Remember that filter-mapping order makes sense, filter executed in the order of their filter mappings are declared. I would try reorder them first.